# How to replace a mathfrak uppercase letter by a "large" lowercase

Tags: fonts, math-mode

My students find it difficult to read (and reproduce) `\mathfrak{S}`. I'd like to replace it with a large `\mathfrak{s}`.

Here is what I've done so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\mathfrak{s}(t) = \mathfrak{S}\cos(\omega t) \\
\mathfrak{s}(t) = \scalebox{1.6}{$\mathfrak{s}$}\cos(\omega t)
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

1. Is there a cleaner way to scale the `\mathfrak{s}`?
2. Is it possible to make `\mathfrak{S}` expands to `\scalebox{1.6}{$\mathfrak{s}$}`?
3. Is there a better aproach?

Comment: Why use mathfrak anyway. I would suggest you just stick with the Latin alphabet (a-z) and the Greek alphabet (alpha - omega) and maybe mathcal for denoting sets. I would never use any Hebrew letters or other custom letters unless it is standard. I do not blame your students either for not being able to repoduce it, it also looks far to much like a ordinary 5. Students don't write their college notes directly in latex you know...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Scaling is surely good with `\scalebox`
2. Define a `\mathfrakS` command along these lines

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
   \usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
   \newcommand{\mathfrakS}{\mathpalette\bigmathfrakS\relax}
   \newcommand{\bigmathfrakS}[2]{\scalebox{1.6}{$#1\mathfrak{s}$}}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{gather}
   \mathfrak{s}(t) = \mathfrakS\cos(\omega t) \\
   \mathfrakS_{\mathfrakS_{\mathfrakS}}
   \end{gather}
   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]
3. Use `\mathfrak{S}` and the students will learn it. Or use a different symbol altogether.

---

Alternative approach, which uses `\mathfrak{S}`, so that you can remove the macros when you decide that a Fraktur S is not a problem any more:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}

\let\ORGmathfrak\mathfrak
\def\mathfrak#1{{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{S}=0 \mathfrakS\else\ORGmathfrak{#1}\fi}}

\newcommand{\mathfrakS}{\mathpalette\bigmathfrakS\relax}
\newcommand{\bigmathfrakS}[2]{\scalebox{1.6}{$#1\ORGmathfrak{s}$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\mathfrak{s}(t) = \mathfrak{S}\cos(\omega t) \\
\mathfrak{S}_{\mathfrak{S}_\mathfrak{S}}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you put the test inside a group in `\def\mathfrak#1{{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{S}=0 \mathfrakS\else\ORGmathfrak{#1}\fi}}`?

Comment: Also, why does `\bigmathfrakS` need two arguments?

Comment: @cjorssen You can use `x_\mathfrak{x}`; for the second argument to `\bigmathfrakS`, look for `\mathpalette` on the site.

Comment: Hum `\mathpalette` is subtle. So that's why there is a `\relax` after `\bigmathfrakS`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `relsize` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,relsize}

\begin{document}
\[
  \mathfrak{s} \mapsto \mathlarger{\mathfrak{s}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want yet larger font, repeat the command.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it answers my question. I don't want the standard `\mathfrak{S}`. Anyway, thanks for mentionning the relsize package.

Comment: @cjorssen: What? You can replace S by s in my solution and you're done, no?

Comment: @cjorssen: See updated answer.